# Can I use selenium to set the dates in the Microsoft Power Bi dashboard?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I try to scrape data from the public [Microsoft Power Bi Dashboard](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNjIwNzg5NzQtNzRlYS00YzFmLWJiNTUtOTM2MGEwY2FjOGJlIiwidCI6ImE3NWRkYWZlLWQ2MmYtNGIxOS04NThhLTllYzFhYjI1NDdkNCIsImMiOjl9) (4th page).

But unfortunately, I can't understand how with selenium I can change periods of time.

Tell me, please, is this even possible using python + selenium? Maybe move these sliders, or enter dates into inputs.
Thanks.
[Dashboard screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMJku.png)

Here is my code to load the dashboard page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
url='https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNjIwNzg5NzQtNzRlYS00YzFmLWJiNTUtOTM2MGEwY2FjOGJlIiwidCI6ImE3NWRkYWZlLWQ2MmYtNGIxOS04NThhLTllYzFhYjI1NDdkNCIsImMiOjl9'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="embedWrapperID"]/div[2]/logo-bar/div/div/div/logo-bar-navigation/span/button[2]/i').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="embedWrapperID"]/div[2]/logo-bar/div/div/div/logo-bar-navigation/span/button[2]/i').click() 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="embedWrapperID"]/div[2]/logo-bar/div/div/div/logo-bar-navigation/span/button[2]/i').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to set the date by clearing the existing date, and then using a date string + tab to refresh the graph, is that what you are looking for?

I also packaged up my attempts to click on the various items with a wait function so I'm not waiting some unnecessary amount of time before something shows up on the screen.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



def InputByXPATH(NameOfObject, WhatToSend):
    try:
        item = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, NameOfObject)))
        item.click()
        item.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
        item.send_keys(WhatToSend)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("InputByXPATH Error: Couldn't input by XPATH on: " + str(NameOfObject))
        pass

def ClickByXPATH(NameOfObject):
    try:
        item = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, NameOfObject)))
        item.click()
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("ClickByXpath Error: Couldn't Click by XPATH on: " + str(NameOfObject))
        pass

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

url='https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNjIwNzg5NzQtNzRlYS00YzFmLWJiNTUtOTM2MGEwY2FjOGJlIiwidCI6ImE3NWRkYWZlLWQ2MmYtNGIxOS04NThhLTllYzFhYjI1NDdkNCIsImMiOjl9'
driver.get(url)
ClickByXPATH('//*[@id="embedWrapperID"]/div[2]/logo-bar/div/div/div/logo-bar-navigation/span/button[2]/i')
ClickByXPATH('//*[@id="embedWrapperID"]/div[2]/logo-bar/div/div/div/logo-bar-navigation/span/button[2]/i')
InputByXPATH('/html/body/div[1]/report-embed/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/exploration-container/div/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container[8]/transform/div/div[3]/div/visual-modern/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input', '2/1/2022' + Keys.TAB )
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shawn. Is that what I need. 
But in my case, clearing the date works only with backspace and sending the date in ''dd.mm.yyyy" format.